# change language in TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I want to change language 'en' to 'ur'. i had downloaded language folder from http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download&pr_id=1, and replaced its three folders **themes, plugins, langs** by tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce folders. 
 and then i had changed full.html code in example folder as mentioned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>آپ سادہ مرکزی خیال</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        language : "ur",
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,fullpage,media,paste,searchreplace,style,table,template,xhtmlxtras",
```

other code is same except for urdu text.

but my output is not showing toolbar, text area.

Please tell what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: It seems you are doing everything correct to change language. However it seems your tinyMCE.init script does not have closing tags. Make sure to put _});_ after _plugins_ line

Comment: @1.44mb, yes tags are closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps which might help you:

1. Include jQuery and `jquery.tinymce.js` file.
2. Assign your `textarea` control the attribute `class="tinymce"`
3. In JavaScript:

   ```
   $(function(){
       $("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
           // Location of TinyMCE script
           script_url : "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js",

           // General options
           theme : "advanced",
           plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

           // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
           content_css : "css/style.css",

           // Theme options
           theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",


       });
   });
   ```